# How to correctly apply a css rule to a nested element

Tags: html, css

I'm starting in CSS now, and I still get confused with the box model, with nested elements, which would be the right thing to apply an alignment to the left of the list, using directly the li element or the ul element

```css
ul {
  background-color: red;
  /*margin-left: -28px*/
}

li {
  margin-left: -28px;
  background-color: green;
}

ul + ul {
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: -28px;
}

ul + ul li {
  margin-left: initial;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>apple</li>
  <li>banana</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>apple</li>
  <li>banana</li>
</ul>
```

What is the difference if I apply a property to ul or li?

Comment: Why do you need negative margin?

Comment: I'm starting in css now and I want to put a list aligned to the left, but this is just an example, I want to know why in nested elements like li element that is inside ul, where should I apply a property, for example, where should I apply the margin-left property to the li element or to the ul element?

Comment: Rather than deciding you need a negative margin, how about telling us your goal and we can help with that? Negative margins may be required, but also if you set `margin` and `padding` on both the `<ul>` and `<li>` I think that might solve your problem. Take a look at the concept of "CSS resets."

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica Actually, I don't want to do anything specific, it was just an example test, I want to know what the difference is when I apply a property to nested elements, for example, in this example, I applied margin-left in both li and ul, I would like to know what is right and what is this behavior?

Comment: I don't know what to possibly explain. The difference is too obvious, no? Style rules take effect on those elements their selector matches.

Comment: That kind of question is far too broad for Stack Overflow, unfortunately. If you apply background colours, and borders, to nested elements and change properties you'll see the difference in your own experiments. If you test cross-browser you'll start to see why CSS resets exist (though they're not quite so necessary any more). To add to connexo's comment, though, bear in mind that CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets; the cascade will also cause CSS to affect some of the descendants of the targeted elements.

Comment: I’m new to programming, I didn’t realize this difference, I’m sorry for my ignorance, I don’t know if I’m making myself understood, I’ll try to rephrase the question better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS works by applying style properties to a selector. In your case the selector is either the `ul`, or `li` elements. Think of the `ul` as a box, and the `li` elements as boxes inside the `ul` box. If you style the `ul` element, only properties which can be inherited will trickle down to the child elements, in this case the `li` elements. [Here is a terrible list of CSS classes](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html), see the "inherit" column.

To answer your question, the `text-align` property is inherited, so if you apply that to the `ul` all of the child elements will inherit that property. This would be the best way to do it since you only have to specify the property once on the parent container.

Beyond that explanation, it sounds like you are trying to remove the spacing from the left of the unordered list. This is how that is done, and an explanation:

- 'ul' elements by default have a padding left, but if you remove the padding, the bullets then overflow the container.
- So what we need is to remove the padding, and to set the `list-style` property to `inside`

```css
body {
  background: #fefefe;
  padding: 30px;
}

ul {
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: inside;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this here, but would there be articles, blogs, in which you recommend me? To follow in css and to get more and more professional, grateful

Comment: I highly recommend Pluralsight. It's not free but it's a great way to learn faster than on Youtube. For a free resource, i like these guys on Youtube: Web Dev Simplified, Kevin Powell, DesignCourse.